# uninitialized constant SurveysController::Survey

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Been trying to figure this error out.  Going to http://localhost:3000/surveys/index.html generates a load_survey error.  I've seen others refer to needing a 'require' clause, but not sure that would make sense (nor how to use it if so).

Really appreciate any help you can provide.

Error
load_survey
app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb, line 53 (starts def load survey):

```
def default_redirect
  redirect_to surveys_path, notice: I18n.t("surveys_controller.#   {action_name}")   
end

def load_survey
  @survey = Survey::Survey.new(params[:id])   
end
```

Full SurveysController code:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  # before_filter :load_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :load_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    type = view_context.get_survey_type(params[:type])
    query = if type then Survey::Survey.where(survey_type: type) else
    Survey::Survey end
    @surveys = query.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(15)
  end

  def new
    @survey = Survey::Survey.new(survey_type: view_context.get_survey_type(params[:type]))
  end

  def create
    @survey = Survey::Survey.new(params_whitelist)

    if @survey.valid? && @survey.save
      default_redirect
    else
      build_flash(@survey)
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    if @survey.update_attributes(params_whitelist)
      default_redirect
    else
      build_flash(@survey)
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @survey.destroy
    default_redirect
  end

  private

    def default_redirect
      redirect_to surveys_path, notice: I18n.t("surveys_controller.#{action_name}")
    end

  def load_survey
    @survey = Survey::Survey.find(params[:id])
  end

  def params_whitelist
    params.require(:survey_survey).permit(Survey::Survey::AccessibleAttributes << :survey_type)
  end

end
```

Comment: Why do you have `Survey::Survey`? Is your model `Survey` actually contained in a **module** called `Survey`?

Comment: Good question - I'm trying to recreate/fix the 'survey gem'.  File structures for views is surveys/index.html, etc.

Comment: however models > user.rb.  There's not an above subfolder.

Comment: Last note: With removing the first survey: of survey::survey, same error appears when running the app.